# Huge difference in apt download speed on HTTP and HTTPS. Why?

Tags: networking, apt, server, ipv6

I have a server (Ubuntu 16.04-3) with three virtual QEMU/KVM servers (2 x Ubuntu 16.04-3 + one Ubuntu 18.04 beta).

Apt download on all the virtual servers is extremely slow from HTTP sources (~ 100kB/s) and fast (~ 3 MB/s) from HTTPS sites. Max. download speed on my internet connection is around 3-3.5 MB/s.

I have disabled ipv6 on all virtual servers without any improvement on HTTP download speed.

What could be the problem, and is there anything I can do to speed up the HTTP apt downloads?

Comment: Do you see the difference between http/https on connections with the same server, or different servers? I'd guess that the servers which coincidentally use http in your case are just generally slower than those who happen to use https, without relevance of the protocol.

Comment: @bytecommander - all three virtual servers (16.04/18.04) have the same problem with HTTP download. Download speeds are always in the 100-120Kb/s range (and HTTPS > 1 MB/s) for each server.

Comment: I did not mean your downloading servers, but the archive servers which host the files. Their bandwidth might be limited more than yours.

Comment: @bytecommander Sorry about the misunderstanding.  However, downloading from (some of these) HTTP sites on another (16.04) computer using a different ISP  shows speeds > 1 MB/s (sometimes > 3 MB/s).